# Is clothing/armor design copyrighted?

Tags: copyright

If I google ''fantasy armor drawings'' or maybe look them on pinterest, and use those drawings of random people to model 3D meshes of armors, is this a copyright violation or can I put them inside my games ?

I mean, I modelled/animated/colored those armors, but they were drawn by someone else.

Why this question? I need to dish out lot's of models, no time to waste designing clothing, I'm not a deisgner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. To get legal counsel, consult a lawyer, not a game development Q&A site.

**Yes**, *ANY* and *EVERY* creative work is subject to copyright, and this is automatic in many jurisdictions of interest.

There is no special carve-out that makes fashion designs, or fantasy-themed fashion designs, exempt from this rule that applies to all creative works.

Even if I go and make a new model or otherwise transpose the work to a different format, that does not give me ownership of the original design. The original creator could object to my unauthorized use of their design, even taking legal action against me.

If you want to use a creative work in your game, you should do one of the following:

- Create your own original work
- Combine, remix, and adapt inspirations you've drawn on in a transformative way, so that what you produce is not just a copy in another format (hoping to use a "Fair Use" defense if legal action were taken against you, though this is not as strong a protection as just making your own work to begin with)
- Seek out creative works that are explicitly offered under a permissive licence (like Creative Commons attribution or public domain licences) and follow the licence terms in your use of the work
- Pay a creator for a licence to use their work in your game
- Hire a creator to produce original works specifically for your game